# Failed to resolve target intent service, Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I try to make **gcm** work.

When our server sends a push notification I got these two errors in my app's log:

> E/GcmReceiver(8049): Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping
>   classname enforcement E/GcmReceiver(8049): Error while delivering the
>   message: ServiceIntent not found.

In my app's folder I got the `google-services.json` file.

I have added the **2 needed services and the receiver** to my Manifest:

```
  <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.myapppackage.application" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <service
        android:name="com.myapppackage.application.gcm.newgcm.RegisterGCMTokenService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>


    <service
        android:name="com.myapppackage.application.gcm.newgcm.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I have **also added these two as java classes.** The gcm token providing and uploading to our server's is fine. **I also got the push 'event' but somehow I got those 2 errors above, and no messages.**

**I have added my project number** from google api console to `strings.xml` as `'google_app_id'`

The API keys should be all right because **I do get the push event, but somehow the message is not provided.**

My gradle's **app level dependencies have:**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.+'
```

My gradle's **project level dependencies have:**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.1'
```

So **what the heck?!** Please help me if you can.

Comment: did you change com.myapppackage.application to your package name ?

Comment: Yes. 11 more characters I must type to send this message.

Comment: You're missing one more service in the manifest. the one that handles the notification and extends GcmListenerService

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have these 3 services in your manifest. You're missing the one with the action **com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE**

```
    <service
        android:name="com.myapppackage.application.gcm.GcmIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.myapppackage.application.gcm.GcmIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.myapppackage.application.gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

Comment: Does the gcmIntentService extend from any other class? From the docs it looks like you should extend GcmListenerService. Do we have to extend both?

Answer (score 1):

Adding firebase messaging dependency worked for me

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
```

Please note that firebase-messaging have a dependency on firebase-analytics

Answer (score 0):

Hey You need to add MyGcmListenerService class for receive notification:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
}
```

you need add this class as service in AndroidMaifest.xml

```
  <service android:name="com.mypackage.application.services.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

just check gradle for required updated and then sync you app and run again
 that's worked for (maybe something wrong in firebase)