# GCM Failed to resolve target intent service

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I tried to get the GCM push notifications working on my Android 6.0.1 device. Unfortunately I'am running into an error.
The log says:

> E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
>   E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.

But I'am not using firebase. 
So why does the log says something about firebase and why does this error happen?

My AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.push.test">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.push.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.push.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    [...] >

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        [...]
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.push.test" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".GcmListener"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->

    <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".InstanceListener"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->

    <service
        android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
</application>
```

My GCMListener.class file:

```
public class GcmListener  extends GcmListenerService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");

    if (from.startsWith("/topics/bewegung")) {
        sendNotification(message);
    }

}
[...]
```

google-service.json is already located in /app.

Marvin

[EDIT:]
Got it!
I registered an wrong topic on initial start.
Now its working perfect.

Comment: are  you able to receive notification?

Comment: @SohailZahid I'am able to register my app and subscribe to an topic, but the mentioned error is thrown on receiving an notification.

Comment: kindly unaccepted my answer so i can delete because its not proper answer and will not help other instead will confuse them.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You should have these 3 services in your manifest. You're missing the one with the action **com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE**

```
    <service
        android:name="com.myapppackage.application.gcm.GcmIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.myapppackage.application.gcm.GcmIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.myapppackage.application.gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

[source thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132798/failed-to-resolve-target-intent-service-error-while-delivering-the-message-ser)

Comment: @EugenPechanec Not the solution, but gave me idea for improvements and i think it's a common mistake.

Comment: Then post your own answer and mark as accepted. Can you imagine if everyone was doing this?

Comment: This is not the answer to the question.