# Error while sending the first notification to all users in Android using FCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm starting to use FCM in my app and today I tried to send a small notification to all users in my app.
I donwoloaded the json just fine and it works fine, no error in the IDE, but the problem comes when I send the notification.

When our server sends a push notification I got these two errors in my app's log:

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping 
classname enforcement

E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

I did not add anything to my AndroidManifest.xml, should I add something to it? I added all the stuff to the Gradle so it's not about that. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you need to add services to your manifest. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36133570/9119277)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure FCM on your application you will need to:

- Add the dependency. E.g.: `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'`
- Create a service that extends `FirebaseMessagingService` and add it to your manifest file. This service will be responsible for processing incoming messages from FCM.
- Create another service that extends `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and also add it to the manifest. This service will be responsible for handling the FCM token creation, update and rotation.

After that, retrieve the FCM token by calling `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` and send it to your server/webservice.

Also, keep in mind that FCM relies on Play Services, so you'll need to check if the device has it installed. You can do that inside the Activity `onCreate()` and/or `onResume()` methods.

More info on how to configure FCM, please [refer to the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).

More on how to [check for Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#public-methods).